# Scrapyd: How to return response when job is finished?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

In the scrapyd docs I couldn't find anyway to override the behavior of how scrapyd sends responses.

So when sending a request to scrapyd:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=project -d spider=spider
```

Instead of receiving this:

```
{"node_name": "local", "status": "ok", "jobid": "7fa5d068969c11e8abbfbc5436cd1f60"}
```

I want to return when the job finished, and whether or not it was successful, like this:

```
{"node_name": "local", "status": "(error or finished)", "jobid": "7fa5d068969c11e8abbfbc5436cd1f60"}
```

Is this possible through a pipeline or something?

Comment: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/55

Comment: we done this the simple way, by checking job status in predefined intervals

Comment: @mirhossein Yes I did the same with a node server acting as a proxy for scrapyd.